# how to print urls in order using for in range in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium

I'm intending to open urls located in the excel files one by one

```
df = pd.read_excel("file", sheet_name="Sheet1"):

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    driver.get()
```

This is what I've searched so far. I'll be appreciated if you give more tips.
cheers!

Comment: Have you considered using Openpyxl instead? Your desired result would be fairly easily achieved with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your spreadsheet has a column heading (e.g., URL) on 'Sheet1' then:

```
import pandas
import requests

df = pandas.read_excel('file.xlsm', sheet_name='Sheet1')

for url in df['URL']:
    requests.get(url)
    # process the response here
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
import os
import time

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver_path = r'D:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()

cwd = os.getcwd()
df = pd.read_csv(cwd + "/csvfile_1.csv")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    driver.get(row['URL'])
    time.sleep(5)
```

and this is how my CSV looks like:

[image]

that `time.sleep(5)` is for visualization purpose, you can remove that once you test this code.